# Force Crystal to Export as Excel Data Only via Registry

Tags: excel, crystal-reports, registry, reporting, export-to-excel

Is there any way to dictate the format of a Crystal Report via the registry? I have come across various registry entries, such as:

HKLM\Software\Business Objects\Suite 11.5\Crystal Reports\Export\Excel
HKCU\Software\Business Objects\Suite 11.5\Crystal Reports Designer Component\Export\Excel

Which contain a number of keys, like MailDestDLL, ExportDirectory, etc.

What I cannot find is any documentation which would contain an entry for me to, for example, write ExcelDataOnly underneath Export, which would force the default export format to be Excel (Date Only). Currently, it is formatted Excel. I realize I can simply select the proper format from within Crystal, but these are automated, so we don't have the option for doing that. I'd like to control as much as possible through the registry as it pertains to the export of reports.

Answer (score 0):

We use a product called VisualCUT that makes it easy to schedule and automate the export, printing, and bursting of reports.

Comment: I only wish we could move to a different application for what we do. As it stands, we are stuck with our existing system, and either I figure out how to export reports automatically as Excel (Data Only), or we get to rewrite hundreds of reports one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you need to rewrite the reports ? 
I am using R-Tag and you can schedule and set the export type, for example excel, pdf, excel data only etc. If you don't have a budget for new software you can use R-Tag Community edition (http://www.r-tag.com/Pages/CommunityEdition.aspx), which is free and still coming with a nice scheduler and plenty of features.

Comment: Because our MRP system has its own scheduler, and I have to work within its confines. The MRP system's export does not easily handle Excel Data Only, although they did rewrite the export module to better handle such exporting requests.

Comment: Still don't understand what is the problem. You need to schedule a report and export it to excel. You know the report, the parameters and when it should run. You have everything necessary to schedule the same report, used by your MRP in an external application and to resolve the issue caused by the existing software. You might contact the vendors of Crystal schedulers. I am sure this is not the first time they do stuff like this.